# PC game involving a dungeon, deadly traps, and a clockwork/robot girl

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Somewhere around 8-10 years ago (around 2008-2010), I downloaded a number of Japanese games and tried to get them working on my machine. One of them, which came to mind recently, I never got working, but it had a number of videos in the game folder that I could read in my video player. All of the times that I remember involved the clockwork/robot girl, who had long hair, pale skin, and a fair light-colored dress, approaching an area with a measured tread that showed no fear or trepidation, only to get mangled by some trap at that location. It looked like computer graphics of the pre-rendered sort (which would make sense for the video files being stored separately).

I don't remember a lot of the specifics, but I think I recall one where she got crushed by a moving wall, and one where she got impaled by spears. In both cases, she seemed unperturbed (which strongly influences my feeling of her as clockwork or a robot), but was eventually disabled by the damage. My memories aren't terribly clear on whether any fluid, gears, or such spilled out, but she cracked on injury, kind of like a doll with plastic skin. I don't recall any success scenarios, but honestly, I only have hazy memories of it. I think I was frustrated by not being able to play it, and deleted it shortly thereafter.

Honestly, given the games I encountered at the time, it might have been an erotic game (there are a lot of those out there, and were the ones most prominent to download), but I don't remember that showing up in any of the videos.

Comment: This is a far better fit on the arqade stackexchange, which deals with videogames exclusively.

Comment: @Theik It's also on-topic here though.

Comment: Could it be one of the early Neptunia games?

Comment: @Theik Arqade doesn't take identification questions without a video, a screenshot, or a soundtrack

Comment: Were the videos in an "anime style?" Or did they look more like 3D PC game graphics?

Comment: When the girl was impaled, crushed, etc. was there blood, sparks, or oil? That might clarify whether she was a clockwork robot versus a human or some kind of biologically engineered clone (like the replicants in Blade Runner).

Comment: Looks like [a ryona genre](http://japanese-hobby.blogspot.com/2018/02/ryona-meaning-in-japanese.html) (**possibly NSFW**, just a text article, no explicit images, but considering the nature of the term)...

Comment: Also, what was your machine? Some old (Japanese) games tend to have bad compatibility with newer OS. Also, you *downloaded* in 2008-2010, but could you remember if the game was released in that year too, or is it possibly a lot older than that?

Comment: @AndrewT.: I believe that, at the time, that was a Windows XP machine that I was operating shortly before I made the jump to Windows 7. Other than that, I forget what the specs were. It was a few machines ago.

Comment: Do you remember any of the other games you downloaded at the time? Downloading a bunch at once makes me think of a doujinsoft collection or something, e.g. shortly after Comiket. If you can remember others that might at least narrow down the timeframe.

Comment: @qazmlpok: Unfortunately, no.